# How to use variable's value (subscriber function) in another function

Tags: python, callback, ros-hydro, rospy, environment-variables

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all !

I want to pass the variable which is set to its value when called the callback function. and then want to use the value of the variable in another function.

```
def where1(msg):
    global x1
    x1 = msg.data
    
def where2(gsm):
    global y1
    y1 = gsm.data
def ground():
    global x1
    global y1
    rospy.init_node("ground")
    rospy.Subscriber("/box_positiona", Float64, where1)
    rospy.Subscriber("/box_positionb", Float64, where2)
        
    print x1
    print y1
    rospy.spin() # this will block untill you hit Ctrl+C

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
            ground()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
            rospy.loginfo("Ground  motion node is shut down.")
```

But i got the following error
**print x1
NameError: global name 'x1' is not defined**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/179523/how-to-use-variable%27s-value-(subscriber-function)-in-another-function/) by [jashanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/14866/jashanvir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2014-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are printing values, i.e. x1, y1 before they have been assigned. The subscribers won't do anything until spin is called and messages are received.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jashanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/14866/jashanvir/) on 2014-06-30**:
But when i check by rostopic echo /box_positiona then it prints the data ?

**Comment by [jashanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/14866/jashanvir/) on 2014-07-01**:
how to get the values from the callback function and use them ? Can you give me the reference or a simple demo code which i can use. ! @dornhege

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-01**:
Try putting your spin() above the print statements.

**Comment by [jashanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/14866/jashanvir/) on 2014-07-01**:
@McMurdo no, it doesnt help...
it prints the value when i terminate the program using ctrl+c

**Comment by [jashanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/14866/jashanvir/) on 2014-07-01**:
@McMurdo no it shows the same error, but this time when i terminate the program.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-02**:
Check your own comment. The spin will retrieve the messages and BLOCK. You should handle message data in the callbacks.

**Comment by [jashanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/14866/jashanvir/) on 2014-07-03**:
Yeah ! I know..
But I solved the problem by putting all these in one class.

**Comment by [DannyMB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28114/dannymb/) on 2016-10-13**:
@jashanvir Hi, can you explain me how do you solved that? I have the same error, other thing, how do you do for use Float64? I am new, and a few noob, in ROS.